# Black banding in viewport (material mode) with normal map

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, normal-map

[image]

1. Model shaded smooth
2. Normal map influencing color
3. Normal map influencing normals in material mode
4. Render of #3

As soon as I apply a normal map the object starts displaying black artifacts. Another thing is that only the active object actually applies the normal map, other objects just glitch. Rendering shows no issues. I'm using Blender Render and Blender 2.79. I have tried switching all settings I could find inside Blender to no avail.

My question is, what causes black bands on #3 and how do I solve it?

**EDIT:**
I tried using Cycles and a similar issue happens, normals are only displayed correctly when the object is selected (I've hidden the wireframe for the screenshot).
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
[image]

Comment: That sounds like a Blender bug to me. Can you share the blend file?

Comment: @MikePan here you go https://www.dropbox.com/s/6h3hpz0wlpr6x2o/NormalBanding.blend?dl=0

Comment: Please use this https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to add the blend in the question

Comment: @Retrax thanks, I uploaded it there also.

Comment: Hmm ive looked through the blend file and I have no artefacts here, are you using experimental builds by any chance ? It could be a bug.

Comment: Sometimes outdated graphics drivers also cause some issues.

Comment: @Retrax I have tried it on another computer and there are no artifacts. Seems the issue is with my computer setup. I will leave the question open just in case I find a solution.